# My VBA Code to Auto FIlter Data will keep previous Criteria reults when Criteria Cell is blank. How can I make it return all the Data instead?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large data set with part numbers that I would like a VBA code wrote to Auto Filter when I enter the part number in a cell. It works great, until I hit delete on the criteria cell, resulting in a Blank cell. It will keep the previous Criteria results instead of unfilter all data.

Previously was helped with an error code, which helped tremendously.  Tried adjusting if statement.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Updateby Extendoffice 20160606
   If Target.Address = Range("$J$2").Address Then
       If Len(Target) > 0 Then
          Range("A2:H50000").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range("J1:J2")
       End If
   End If
End Sub
```

I would like the data to return ALL Unfiltered instead of previous Filtered Criteria, when the Criteria Cell is left blank.

Comment: I added a comment to your previous question. Might be as simple as `activesheet.showalldata`.

Comment: I made the revision and its still showing the previous filtered criteria.

Comment: Where did you put that line? Needs to be an else clause in the inner If.

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Updateby Extendoffice 20160606
   If Target.Address = Range("$J$2").Address Then
       If Len(Target) > 0 Then
          Range("A2:H50000").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=ActiveSheet.ShowAllData, CriteriaRange:=Range("J1:J2")
       End If
   End If
End Sub

Comment: As you can see code is unreadable in comments. Please add to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$J$2" Then  'don't need the range bit
    If Len(Target) > 0 Then
       Range("A2:H50000").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range("J1:J2")
    Else
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This is perfect.  Thank you!